# bypassing slow ISP-specified DNS servers with Ununtu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns

I have FTTC NBN (it's an Assie thing) feeding a router (I've tried TP-Link and Sagemcom) over PPPoE.   I set the desired DNS IP's in the router but when I activate the PPPoE connection, the router overwrites those IP's with ones specified by my ISP and will not allow them to be changed.

I need a way for Ubuntu to ignore those SLOW nameservers and use the ones I specify.

At the moment, my WAN connection (I have two ethernet NICs in the box) settings are specified by DHCP from the router and the nameserver specs come with that connection from the router.  I can only think that if I instead, configure the WAN NIC to be a static IP, the router's nameserver info wont be forced across and all my settings can be implemented in the appropriate netplan file.   Any comments, suggestions?
Peter

Comment: I generally hate posters who deluge a bunch of acronyms without explanation - as I have here .  Anyone who wants them explained, just say so - I will comply.